# different setters for python properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, setter, getter-setter

I have a class

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name='', num_of_owners=0, sleep=0):
        self.name = name
        self.num_of_owners = int(float(num_of_owners))
        self.sleep = float(sleep)
```

let's say I'm reading all the properties from some file.

I'm using Properties for getters and setters.

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self.name

@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    self.name = value
```

now when reading from the file, I don't want to look for every property in the dictionary i got specifically.

So i can run a for over the dictionary and type

```
for name, value in animal_props.iteritems():
     setattr(animal, name, value)
```

but then all the properties are set as strings.
The thing is I have about 8 properties some floats some int some strings.

Anyway to run this for, and not make regular setters and run a specific setter for each property.

example:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name='', num_of_owners=0, sleep=0):
        self._name = name
        self._num_of_owners = int(float(num_of_owners))
        self._sleep = float(sleep)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    @property
    def num_of_owners(self):
        return self._num_of_owners

    @num_of_owners.setter
    def num_of_owners(self, value):
        self._num_of_owners = int(value)

    @property
    def sleep (self):
        return self._sleep

    @sleep.setter
    def sleep(self, value):
        self._sleep = int(float(value))

d = {'name': 'doggy', 'num_of_owners': '3', 'sleep': '5.643'}
dog = Animal()
for name, value in d.iteritems():
    setattr(dog, name, value)

print type(dog.sleep)
```

I need the type at the end to be float. since i will later use it as a float.

Creating separate 'ifs' and send to each setter is fine, but is there anyway to do it with just that one for.

Comment: works for me. please show a minimal example, that shows the error.

Comment: All the code you've shown is nonsense. You're creating an old-style class (because you are using Python 2 and not inheriting from `object`), which can't use properties. If you could, you'd get infinite recursion, since the getter requests itself and the setter assigns to itself (you probably want to use `_name` or something similar for the "real" attribute underlying the property). Beyond those errors, I have absolutely no idea what you're actually asking here. What are you trying to do? Why do you thing `property` is related to doing it? What's going wrong?

Comment: added example of what i want happening. @Daniel

Comment: @Blckknght added exapmle. not so difficult

Comment: Because your dictionary, all the values are strings. Remove the ' around the numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using python 2 with old-style classes. Properties are only available with new-style classes:

```
class Animal(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're really using Python 2 (as your tag suggests), you need to change your class declaration so that you inherit from `object`. Doing so will make your class a "new style" class rather than an "old-style" class (which were the only kind of class back in the Python 2.1 days). If you don't know much about these two kinds of class, don't worry about learning about the old ones. Just create new-style classes always (they're the only kind in Python 3).

To make a new-style class, inherit from object:

```
class Animal(object):
    #...
```

Note that if you're not doing type conversions or other kinds of validation in your property getter or setter methods (as with `name` in your example code), you might as well get rid of the whole property and just use a regular attribute instead. If you find you do need validation later on in your program's design, you can switch back to using a property at that point and the other parts of the code that read or write from the attribute won't need to change.